# Flex Datagrid Query

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, events, click

Below is part of my code interacting with data grid...!

This lists the children of the particular node if i click on it after refreshing the datagrid..

But if i click on an empty space of the datagrid i get an error saying

"ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property data not found on mx.controls.listClasses.ListBaseContentHolder and there is no default value."

How to avoid that ?

if(event.target.data.children != null)
        {
            resultSet.removeAll();
            var tempChildObj:ArrayCollection;
            tempChildObj=event.target.data.children as ArrayCollection;
            var childLength:int;
            childLength=tempChildObj.length;

```
        for(var i:int =0;i<childLength;i++)
        {

            resultSet.addItem(tempChildObj.getItemAt(i));

        }

        resultSet.addItem(tempChildObj);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error is telling you is that the event's `target` property doesn't have a property called `data` in your error case. This makes sense since you're clicking on a blank row - a blank row won't contain any data.

What you'll want to do first is check if the event's `target` contains a `data` property before you start accessing the `child` property of `data`. Either one of the following tests should work:

```
if( event.target.hasOwnProperty( "data" ) ) {
    // rest of your code here
}
```

or

```
if( event.target.data ) {
    // rest of your code here
}
```